# С помощью setTimeout добавлять класс

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

Необходимо добавлять класс, по очереди, блокам которые находятся в `v-for`, каждые n-секунд и удалять предыдущим. Чтобы, к примеру, каждую секунду появляся новый блок, а старый удалялся и так зациклить.

```
<div v-for="(block, index) in blocks" :key="index" class="blockItem">{{block.title}}</div>
data: () => ({
    blocks: [
      {
        title: 'Раз',
      },
      {
        title: 'Два',
      },
      {
        title: 'Три',
      },
    ],
  }),
```

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Не совсем понятно,  причем здесь классы. Не могли бы вы подсказать что к чему в вашем вопросе?

Comment: @MikalaiParakhnevich к примеру каждый 5 секунд блоку blockItem по индексу 0, потом 1 и т.д. добавлять класс active. Чтобы сначала показался блок с текстом "Раз", потом "Два" и там постоянно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы оперировать данными из массива, необходимо полагаться, что каждый элемент имеет уникальный идентификатор.

Создаем в `data` переменную - `idActiveBlock`, в которой будем хранить индекс активного элемента из массива `blocks` (того, элемента, которому нужно присвоить класс css - `active`). В `template` добавляем соответствующие выражения, которые будут формировать классы для элементов из массива, полагаясь на данные:

```
<div v-for="block in blocks" :key="block.id" :class="['blockItem', {active: block.id === idActiveBlock}]">
  {{block.title}}
</div>
```

Создаем функцию, которая будет отвечать за изменение индекса активного элемента, в которой после манипуляций с индексом, формируем отложенный запуск этой же функции еще раз, через заданный промежуток времени.

Для управления отображением можно использовать `css` стили.

Для наглядности пример:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    run: false,
    timer: null,
    idActiveBlock: 0,
    blocks: [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'Раз',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Два',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Три',
      },
    ],
  }),
  methods: {
    toggleStart() {
      this.run = !this.run
      if (this.run) {
        this.editParamsActiveBloks()
      } else {
        clearTimeout(this.timer)
      }
    },
    editParamsActiveBloks() {
      this.idActiveBlock = this.idActiveBlock < this.blocks.length ? this.idActiveBlock + 1 : 1
      const idNextActiveElement = this.blocks[this.idActiveBlock - 1].id || 0
      if (this.run) {
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.editParamsActiveBloks, 1000);
      }
    },
  },
})
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.blockItem {
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: .2;
  background: #eee;
}

.active {
  background: #42b883;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Индекс активного блока = {{idActiveBlock}}
  <div class="flex">
    <div v-for="block in blocks" :key="block.id" :class="['blockItem', {active: block.id === idActiveBlock}]">
      {{block.title}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button @click="toggleStart">
    <template v-if="run">Стоп</template>
    <template v-else>Старт</template>
  </button>
</div>
```